# SWIFT 3: How to add headers to columns in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a TableView in my app which contains 3 columns(Date, Name & Amount) whose values are fetched from Core data. I am able to display these values in my App.

Now I want to provide fixed header names to every column which doesn't go on scrolling down the list. But I am not getting any way of adding multiple headers to my table list.

Anyone has any idea about the same?

Implemented method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        
        let view = UIView()
        let label = UILabel()
        
        switch section {
        case 0:
            label.text="Date"
        case 1:
            label.text="Name"
        case 2:
            label.text="Amount"
        default:
            print()
        }
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        return view
    }
```

Adding screenshot of my Table View.

[image]

Comment: could you please add your `tableview` implementation or , the screenshot of your current `tableview`

Comment: Added the screenshot

Comment: I need see  your result view @NGR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to find  the solution. It's about adding a View section just at the top of prototype. And then add labels/column name to that view. It will work. No need to make any change in TableViewController class.

Comment: How about the alignment?

Answer (score 1):

Use tableview sections for this, using the following method pass your custom section header

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: Thanks Navneet for reply. Can you elaborate your answer more? I tried to implement that method. But no success so far. Updating the original post with implemented method.

Comment: Implementing the heightForHeaderInSection method will call viewForHeaderInSection and set the header

Comment: But how to have 3 values in single header for each column?

Comment: You can create another tableview cell. Create cell, out in the values and return it the same way we do in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1):

> But I am not getting any way of adding multiple headers to my table list

Correct. You don't have multiple columns, really, either; you have a single column with three things in each row. Similarly, you need to make a section header which *also* has three things in a row. In other words, your `table​View(_:​view​For​Header​In​Section:​)` implementation needs to return a *view* containing three labels side by side, saying "Date", "Name", and "Amount", exactly as your *cell* contains three labels side by side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are doing correct just set the CGRect for label and view in viewForHeaderInSection and you can set the height of headerSection

```
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 61.0
}
```